# Passing object as props to jsx. Without {...obj}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I have an array from redux

```
let profiles = this.props.blocks.profiles.map(prof => {

    let arrayRows = {
        name: prof.name,
        version: prof.version,
        description: prof.description,
        community: prof.community
    }
    return (
        <MyComponent
            name={prof.name}
            custmProps
            custmProps
            custmProps
            {...arrayRows} // here I don't want this
        // I need object, which contains key-value from arrayRows
        />
    )

})
```

Because I want to create universal component, which can have 'n key-value prop with. So in MyComponent I have smt like this:

```
<myComponent>
    {this.props.title /* every component must have this */} 
    {this.props.id /* every component must have this */} 
    {this.props.arrayRows.map(arr => { 
        return (
            <BlockRow 
                blockRowName={arr.key} // here: name || version || description || community || ...
                blockRowVal={arr.val} // here: name.val || version.val || description.val || community.val || ...
            />
        )
    })}
</myComponent>
```

In Store I have array with objects. Each object have his own properties. This connection works fine

**UPDATE**

Reducer:

```
const initialState = { 
    profiles: [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Profile 1',
            version: '23',
            description: 'description',
            community: 'community'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Profile 2',
            version: '23',
            description: 'description',
            community: 'community'
        }
    ]
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        blocks: state.myReducer
    };
};
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Andy Ho to pass object to props, without using {...obj}?

Comment: @РомаХр why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Andy because I don't know how many keys it will be and which name these keys will have. Maybe there are 50 unique names. I don't want to create 50 times MyComponent to check if  this props exist

Answer (score 1):

Edit: you are doing a map twice
What you are passing to your MyComponent is an element of your full array.
Remove the map that's on this level.
Pass the full array to MyComponent

```
return (
    <MyComponent
        name={prof.name}
        custmProps
        custmProps
        custmProps
        arrayRows={this.props.blocks.profiles} // here you want this
    />
)
```

Comment: I tryed this and have TypeError: this.props.arrayRows.map is not a function

Comment: @РомаХр can you edit your question to include your actual code for MyComponent

Comment: Done. You can see it

Comment: @Рома Хр I've edit my answer. It's because you are passing a single array element in MyComponent.

Comment: Thank you, but it still undefined. If I find answer, I will write here

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass down an entire object as props as you would any other prop:

```
<MyComponent
    rows={arrayRows}
/>
```

And access it like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({rows}) => {
    console.log(rows);

    return null;
}
```

There is no need to de-structure it.
You will still be able to access your key-value pairs this way.

Comment: Good Idea. But I have a Component class, because inside MyComponent I have few btns, which do actions in mapDispatchToProps. Ho to correct pass  ({rows}) in that way?

Comment: @РомаХр Can you please provide your code for `mapDispatchToProps`? It'll make it easier to understand your case and to help solve it.

Comment: Updated. Nothing difficult

Answer (score 0):

The most ES6 way is:
the object will have the same name as the prop, than:

```
return (
<MyComponent
    name={prof.name}
    custmProps
    custmProps
    custmProps
    arrayRows // here what you need
/>
```

)